# How to round of date with momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

1) My Accurate date is :**Tue Apr 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530**

2) But in Calendar when i am selecting time i was get like this 
**Tue Apr 24 2019 16:56:00 GMT+0530**

I was tried to fix below way

```
moment($scope.ProjectModel.projectStartDate).startOf('day')
```

But I am getting **Tue Apr 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530**
This one is not correct, correct date: **Tue Apr 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530**

So what i need to do to get this date ?

Comment: Do you really want it set to Midnight Sri Lanka time? Or Midnight Zulu time?

Comment: The problem is not with moment. Please explain more about `But in Calendar when i am selecting time...`

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like you want to set the date to the start of the next day, rather than the start of the current one. You can do it like this:

```
moment($scope.ProjectModel.projectStartDate).startOf('day').add(1, 'days');
```

Or, it seems like you want to round up if the provided date is noon or later, and down otherwise. In this case, just add 12 hours before going to the start of the day:

```
moment($scope.ProjectModel.projectStartDate).add(12, 'hours').startOf('day');
```

Comment: This is not proper way bro, some times the date was accurate so how to round of the date ?

Comment: When you say _round_ the date, do you mean that you will round up if the provided date is noon or later? And down otherwise? If so, just add 12 hours instead of 1 day.